# Single consumer bind to multiple endpoint

Tags: c#, masstransit

I am trying to bind a single consumer to multiple endpoints. Is this possible?

My consumer

```
class OrderPlacedConsumer : IConsumer<OrderPlaced>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<OrderPlaced> context)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

The way I register my consumer and bus.

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<OrderPlacedConsumer>();

    x.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
    {
        //Read RabbitMq setting from config 
        string connectionString = config.ConnectionStrings.RabbitMQConnString;
        RabbitMQSetting rabbitMQSetting = GetRabbitMQSetting(connectionString);
        cfg.Host(rabbitMQSetting.Host, (ushort)rabbitMQSetting.Port, "/", h =>
        {
            h.PublisherConfirmation = false;
            h.Username(rabbitMQSetting.UserName);
            h.Password(rabbitMQSetting.Password);
            h.Heartbeat(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(rabbitMQSetting.Heartbeat));
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("endpoint1", e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer(ctx, OrderPlacedConsumer);

            #region Exchange
            e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
            e.Bind("OrderExchange", x =>
            {
                x.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                x.RoutingKey = "endpoint1";
            });
            #endregion
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("endpoint2", e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer(ctx, OrderPlacedConsumer);

            #region Exchange
            e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
            e.Bind("OrderExchange", x =>
            {
                x.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                x.RoutingKey = "endpoint2";
            });
            #endregion
        });
    });
});
```

However, "OrderPlacedConsumer" consumer is only bound to "endpoint1". Is it possible to bind it to "endpoint2" as well.

Answer (score 1):

It should properly configure the consumer using the proper syntax:

```cs
e.ConfigureConsumer<OrderPlacedConsumer>(ctx);
```